# Select Distinct for only one column of value for Access

Tags: sql, select, distinct

I want doing a datalistview of a product page.

Here is what I am using have now:

```
SELECT DISTINCT pProductDesign, pProductImage 
FROM Product 
WHERE (pProductDesign IS NOT NULL) 
ORDER BY pProductImage
```

The results are:

> pProductDesign|pProductImage
>
> 128101 |~/Images/128101-Cream.jpg
>   128101 |~/Images/128101-Gold.jpg
>
> 128101 |~/Images/128101-Khaki.jpg
>
> 8680C |~/Images/8680C-Cream.jpg
>
> 8680C |~/Images/8680C-Gold.jpg
>   8680C |~/Images/8680C-Khaki.jpg

But what I want is just:

> pProductDesign|pProductImage
>
> 128101 |~/Images/128101-Cream.jpg
>
> 8680C |~/Images/8680C-Khaki.jpg

Is there anyway to do it!?

Comment: What are your criteria for choosing which `ProductImage` should be chosen for each `ProductDesign`? That is, why is `Cream` the correct choice for `128101` and `Khaki` correct for `8680C`?

Comment: @goric it is not a correct choice, because I am doing like a category page for the design, so I just need the unique Product design name and any of its corresponding image to show as a sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're just looking for a distinct list of `ProductDesign`s and some arbitrary associated `ProductImage` for each (as alluded to in the comments), you can use any aggregation function (`min`, `max`, `average`) with a `group by`:

```
select ProductDesign, max(ProductImage)
from Product
where ProductDesign is not null
group by ProductDesign
```